# Find all selected check boxes in razor generated html via jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to capture all selected check boxes generated by razor foreach coming from an MVC model. I need to do this using Jquery.

I've tried capturing the what is selected and what is not. I've managed to find one, but that's it. I assume it's due to the way the html is layed out. There's only one actual input.

I have tried the using, which gets me the value of the checkbox input and a count of how many are checked, but I need the value of the DisplayFor instead.

```
  $('#mcalSubmit').on('click', function () {
    var subLines = [];
    $.each($("input[name='subLines']:checked"), function () {
        favorite.push($(this).val());
    });
    alert( subLines.join(", "));

});
```

I have these divs here and I fill out a table using a foreach based on a model from a separate db. The user selects the check box next to the Displayfor ..

```
<div class="card text-white bg-info mb-3 ml-3 hideMe " id="MCAL" style="min-width: 25rem; max-width: 25rem; ">
        <div class="card-header bg-primary">
            MCAL Sublines
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <table id="mcalTBL" class="table">
                <tr></tr>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    ULT = item.UniqLineType;
                    if (ULT == AL)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td class="text-white ">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="cbMCAL" value="sublineMcal" />
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SubLine_Name)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer bg-secondary">
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-md float-right" id="mcalSubmit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I need to find a way to capture which checkboxes they select and the table row data (in this case it would be which DisplayFor item did they select) .. I have to do this because I will then send these to a controller for db insertion after. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Sam Axe, I edited and added what I've found that partially works so far.

Comment: Why not use `CheckBoxFor`?

Comment: Heretic monkey.. replace DisplayFor with checkbox for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add this code

```
  $('#mcalSubmit').on('click', function () {
    var subLines = "";
    $.each($("input[name='subLines']:checked"), function () {
       subLines += $(this).val() +","
    });
   alert(subLines);
  });
```

also add

```
    name='subLines' // add in your input checkbox code
   <input type="checkbox" name='subLines' class="cbMCAL" value="sublineMcal" />
```

in your checkbox code

Comment: Thanks faseeh. I'll try that when I get back to my comp

Comment: you're welcome, get back to me if you feel any question.

Comment: I edit some code according to your code, so that it become easy for you. you can use it easily now.

Comment: Hi Faseeh. Your assistance was really helpful. Thank you. I changed two small things on my code and the code you gave to me. I wrapped the the Html.DisplayFor in a span tag and changed val() to html. Along with what the .push looks for. And it works great. I'll post so you can see.

Comment: Sounds great :)